# Do research choices and unit upgrades carry over into Multiplayer?

Tags: starcraft-2

I haven't dared touch multiplayer in StarCraft 2 yet but was wondering if the research points I'm spending and unit upgrades I choose in Campaign mode will carry over into my multiplayer games?

I don't know much about the game but want to pick what appeals the most rather than the *de  facto* choices but thought this might hamper me when I get into MP.  I'll need all the help I can get :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, since this would imbalance Terran vs the other two classes

The big advantage of splitting these two, is that they can do very cool stuff in the Campaign, while maintaining balance in multiplayer. This is a very big problem for World of Warcraft, where this has lead to numerous 'nerfs' of special abilities to maintain balance in Player vs Player.

Comment: Another nice change in separating campaign and multiplayer was how they added in more units to campaign, like bringing back Vultures and Wraiths for some missions.

Comment: And firebats, medics, and science vessels!

Comment: Ok thanks.  Sounds like I'll be doing a lot of learning when I hit the multiplayer!  Do the skirmishes against the AI limit you to those units available in MP?  I wouldn't want to go into my first MP match thinking "Arggh, where are my xyz units!"

Comment: @DazLewis Yes, when you're doing skirmish matches vs the AI, you will be playing on the multiplayer ruleset.

Comment: Er, WoW has a single player?

Comment: @Blue: PvE vs PvP.

Comment: i wish the diamondback was a real unit in multiplayer :(